# How should i run sample code from github for kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect.toolbox, ofxkinect

I have downloaded a source code from GitHub  for kinect but I don't understand how to install and run it. Please help me, I am a beginner with kinect and what reference could I use for kinect?

Thank you!

[Here](https://github.com/LightBuzz/Kinect-Finger-Tracking) is the code:

Comment: it's work perfectly on mine have you install sdk of kinect ?

Comment: yes i install 1.8 kinect sdk and i am using xbox 360 kinect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following:

-Kinect SDK from Microsoft.
-Download the Microsoft Samples for kinect.
-Choose a platform for development.
-Here is a tutorial with samples: https://github.com/Kinect/tutorial